# JavaScript: refer to anonymous class static variable

Tags: javascript, web-component

Following [this google tutorial on web components](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#define), and I like the way the author uses an anonymous class in the `customElements.define` function call, as it avoids even more brackets when creating an immediately invoked function call.

I am using a [static class variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#static_methods_and_properties) to store the template element, so it's not queried every time the custom tag is instantiated.

The problem is in `connectedCallback` I don't know how to refer to class name since it is an anonymous function. In python one could to `type(self)`, but my research shows that `typeof this` does not work in JS due to prototype magic.

```
window.customElements.define('my-uploader', class extends HTMLElement {
    static template = document.getElementById("TEMPLATE_UPLOADER");

    constructor() {
        super(); // always call super() first
    }

    /** Custom Component Reactions **/
    connectedCallback() {
        let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
        shadowRoot.appendChild(document.importNode(ANONYMOUS_NAME.template, true));  // <--- How to refer to the class name here?
    }
```

How to refer to the class' `ANONYMOUS_NAME` in `connectedCallback`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either name your class, it's the cleanest way, or you can use `this.constructor` to get your static variable value :

```js
window.customElements.define('my-uploader', class extends HTMLElement {
    static template = document.getElementById("TEMPLATE_UPLOADER");

    constructor() {
        super(); // always call super() first
    }

    /** Custom Component Reactions **/
    connectedCallback() {
        let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
        shadowRoot.appendChild(document.importNode(this.constructor.template, true)); 
    }
```

Comment: That is so bizarre, `this.constructor`, I would have never of guessed that. Thank you that is eactly what I was after. Was trying `Object.getPrototype(this).template` and other none successfull ways. Did not want to use a class and its not DRY, and IIFE have so many brackets and are hard to maintain to me. Cheers!

Comment: 1 Year later I have the same question, thank you again for this answer!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you twice! See you next year, maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

When working with shadowDOM you (in general) create everything in the `constructor`

The `connectedCallback` triggers for every DOM insertion OR DOM CHANGE!
Think Drag/Drop interactions, or sorting DOM Elements.
It will error if you try to attach a shadowRoot **again**

You can chain all JS, see below

`importNode` is for multiple Documents; you will see `cloneNode` in the better blogs.

`append` has more power, see the docs.
It just wasn't available in IE, so old JS-Geezers don't know about it.

```js
customElements.define('my-uploader', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        let template = document.getElementById("TEMPLATE_UPLOADER").content;
        // don't believe the (MDN) documentation, you CAN execute JS BEFORE super()
        // you just can't access 'this' BEFORE super()
        super() // super sets AND returns the 'this' scope
          .attachShadow({mode: "open"}) // sets AND returns this.shadowRoot;
          .append(template.cloneNode(true)); 
    }
});
```

```html
<template id="TEMPLATE_UPLOADER">
  <style>
   :host{
    color:red;
   }
  </style>
  <h1>I am <slot></slot></h1>
</template>

<h1>Hello Web Components!</h1>
<my-uploader>Uploader!</my-uploader>
```

Note! The `constructor` also runs on `document.createElement("my-uploader")` when your Element DOES NOT EXIST in DOM yet! Only when added to the DOM the `connectedCallback` runs

Comment: Create info as always, thanks Danny!